# Defining cross-module variables with values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm developing a bunch of Excel Macros for making my life easier. One part of different macros is inserting a picture into sheets. For this reason, I would like to save the path to the images in a global location and then access it via a variable (so that I don't have to manually adjust the paths in every macro if it changes). I use one module per macro

In my own module "Variables" I defined a variable as Public or Global and then assigned a value via a sub. If I now access this variable via another module, I get an empty MsgBox. 
For test purposes I use a string which I want to display via an MsgBox.

Modul 1:

```
Public test As String
Sub variablen()
    test = "String for Test "
End Sub
```

Modul 2:

```
Public Sub testpublic()
    MsgBox (test)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is working- you have to set test variable value by running "variablen" Sub, after that the "testpublic" Sub is working as you expect. If you run only testpublic, than test variable is empty. But the below solution is better than setting variable value in Sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a constant instead of a variable:

**Module 1**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const MyPath As String = "C:\Temp"
```

**Module 2**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowPath()
    MsgBox MyPath
End Sub
```

I also recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

---

If you do it like you did `test` is empty until it was initialized by running the procedure `variablen` first. If you use `Public Const` no initialization is required.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> *so that I don't have to manually adjust the paths in every macro if it changes*

If it ever needs to change, then it semantically isn't a `Const`. The key to writing code that you don't constantly need to modify is to separate the *code* from the *data*.

A file path that *sometimes* needs to change can be seen as some kind of configuration setting.

Have a module that is able to read the settings from wherever they are, and return the value of a setting given some *key*.

The settings themselves can live on a (hidden?) worksheet, in a `ListObject` table with `Key` and `Value` columns, and looked up with `INDEX`+`MATCH` functions (using the early-bound `WorksheetFunction` functions will throw run-time errors given a non-existing key string):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetSettingValue(ByVal key As String) As Variant
    With SettingsSheet.ListObjects(1)
        GetSettingValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
            .ListColumns("Value").DataBodyRange, _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(key, .ListColumns("Key").DataBodyRange, 0))
    End With
End Function
```

The `Variant` will retain the subtype of the `Value`, so for a `String` value you get a `Variant/String`; for a `Date` value you get a `Variant/Date`, for a numeric value you get a `Variant/Double`, and for a TRUE/FALSE value you get a `Variant/Boolean`.

Now when the file path needs to change, your code does not:

```
Dim path As String
path = GetSettingValue("ImageFolderPath")
```

And if you need more settings, you have no code to add, either:

```
Dim otherThing As String
otherThing = GetSettingValue("OtherThing")
```

All you need to do is to make sure the string keys being used match the contents of the `Key` column in your `SettingsSheet`.